# How to get foreign repository inside my repository in Doctrine2/Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, repository

I need values from 2 different entities. I don't know how to do.
I tried this so far:

```
<?php

namespace Pond\GeolocBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * PondLakeRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class PondLakeRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function getSwimsAvailableById($id)
    {
        // get the nb of swims of a lake
        $lake = $this->findOneById($id);
        $swims = $lake->getSwims();

        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                           ->getManager()
                           ->getRepository('PondGeolocBundle:User_Lake');

        //get the nb of users in a lake
        $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('count(a.id)');
        $qb->from('PondGeolocBundle:User_Lake', 'a');

        $nbOfUsers = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();

        // return the nb of swims available onthis lake
        $avail = $swims - $nbOfUsers;
        print_r ($avail);
    }

}
```

Doesn't work
Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can access the `EntityManager` by calling [`Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository#getEntityManager()`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php#L246-L252):

```php
$repository = $this
    ->getEntityManager()
    ->getRepository('PondGeolocBundle:User_Lake');
```

Comment: Since you didn't specify it in your answer (and OP didn't spicify it in question), I want to let you know that since symfony2.2 `->getEntityManager()` is deprecated and with symfony3, it will be removed.

Use `->getManager()` if you already have symfony2.2

Comment: @DonCallisto `getEntityManager` is a doctrine method, and has nothing to do with Symfony2. Is symfony2 setting custom repositories automatically?

Comment: @Ocramius: actually you're right. So it seems like I've upgraded to symfony2.2 and doctrine (another version) at the same time and have confused this. Actually comment was posted on the same days that I start to remove all deprecated calls and I've done a "mind-cut-and-paste" :)

Comment: @DonCallisto no problem, it's just that doctrine and symfony are independent projects :)

Comment: @Ocramius: yeah I perfectly know, but your comment was useful since I told something wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

If you like more to inject dependencies, declare your repositories as services so you can inject one to use it inside the other:

**services.yml**

```
services:
    repository.user_lake:
        class: Pond\GeolocBundle\Entity\UserLakeRepository
        factory: [@doctrine, getRepository]
        arguments:
            - PondGeolocBundle:User_Lake

    repository.pond_lake:
        class: Pond\GeolocBundle\Entity\PondLakeRepository
        factory: [@doctrine, getRepository]
        arguments:
            - PondGeolocBundle:PondLake
        calls:
            - [setUserLakeRepository, [@repository.user_lake]]
```

in PondLakeRepository.php you must have a setter (setUserLakeRepository) to a property to store the repository (i.e. $userLakeRepository).