# Get Doctrine inside Symfony 2.4 Entity Listener

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using the new [Entity Listeners](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners) which are working great for the Entity that triggers them. However, in the Listener I want to access data from other Entities, essentially make some database requests.

To do this I am using a [setter injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html#setter-injection)

```
<?php 

// Project/DefaultBundle/EventListener/SomeIndexer.php

namespace Project\DefaultBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Project\DefaultBundle\Entity\Document;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class SomeIndexer
{

    protected $em;

    public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function prePersist(Document $doc, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        // this is my Document entity which works fine
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

        if ( $entity instanceof Document )
        {
            // em doesn't seem to be an object
            $this->em->getRepository('ProjectDefaultBundle:SomeOtherEntity') ...
        }
    }

}
```

and in my services config

```
// Project/DefaultBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

services:
    timeline.eventlistener.tripindexer:
        class: Project\DefaultBundle\EventListener\SomeIndexer
        calls:
        - [setEntityManager, ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the incorrect assumption that `$entityManager` was only for the Document Entity. In fact you don't need to inject anything, you can simply use:

```
$repository = $entityManager->getRepository('ProjectDefaultBundle:SomeOtherEntity')...
```

via [How to get foreign repository inside my repository in Doctrine2/Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466513/how-to-get-foreign-repository-inside-my-repository-in-doctrine2-symfony2)